# Ionic Menu Links are Only Usable Once

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, ionic5

I am developing a mobile app using ionic angular. I have a three tab bar across the bottom of my screen (routing works fine). On one of these tabs I have a menu that is used to navigate to further pages in that tab. However when using the menu it only seems to work once? if I refresh or move to another tab and return it works for only one time. I understand this was a bug in angluar 4 so I have run `npm i -g ionic/angular` in the hopes to solve this. Running `ionic -info`I get

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2
```

so surely this issue should be resolved? I am now thinking it is an error in my routing

**/app-routing-module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'app',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my app-routing-module which loads my tabs page by default

my tabs page has a series of child pages which all load ok

**./tabs-routing-module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'homemenu',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'homemenu',
        loadChildren: () => import('../homemenu/homemenu.module').then( m => m.HomemenuPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: () => import('../settings/settings.module').then( m => m.SettingsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () => import('../account/account.module').then( m => m.AccountPageModule)
      },
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

My Menu page loads the home module by default

**./homemenu-routing-module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomemenuPage } from './homemenu.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {

    path: '',
    component: HomemenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'page2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../page2/page2.module').then( m => m.Page2PageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'page3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../page3/page3.module').then( m => m.Page3PageModule),
      }
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomemenuPageRoutingModule {}
```

my menu links are shown in my homemenu-page.ts

**./ homemenu-page.ts**

```
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homemenu',
  templateUrl: './homemenu.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homemenu.page.scss'],
})
export class HomemenuPage implements OnInit {
  pages =[
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: 'home'

    },
    {
      title: 'Page2',
      url: 'page2'

    },
    {
      title: 'Page3',
      url: 'page3'

    },    
  ];

  selectedPath = '';

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.selectedPath = event.url;
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have followed the routing through and it seems like it should all work okay? I am missing something? note this issue works from any link. If I load any link in the menu it will work once until i try to navigate again and it will not route me to the new page the menu will just disapear but with no new page or new URL

**Update**: I have uninstalled Ionic and Reinstalled with No results

```
npm uninstall ionic

npm install ionic
```

If I right click the menu and open in a new tab everything works fine? **If my routing looks okay please let me know and I will remove that code from the post!**

Here is the homemenu.page.ts if this helps

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homemenu',
  templateUrl: './homemenu.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homemenu.page.scss'],
})
export class HomemenuPage implements OnInit {
  pages =[
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: 'home'

    },
    {
      title: 'Page 1',
      url: 'page1'

    },
    {
      title: 'Page2',
      url: 'Page2'

    },    
  ];

  selectedPath = '';

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.selectedPath = event.url;
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem here is about `routerLink` since you don't completely post the html file of the component.
Did you try to use alternative way on navigation?
e.g,(Not working)

In typescript

```js
// custom.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

pageTitle = [
    {title: 'home', icon: 'home'}, {title: 'post', icon: 'reader'},
    {title: 'order', icon: 'list'}, {title: 'inbox', icon: 'mail'},
    {title: 'notification', icon: 'notifications'}
    ];
```

In html

```html
    <!-- custom.html --> 
<ion-item [routerLink]="[menu.title]" lines="none" *ngFor="let menu of pageTitle"> <ion-icon [name]="menu.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon> <ion-label>{{menu1.title | titlecase}}</ion-label> </ion-item>
```

Solution:
Instead of using routerLink attribute you can used an alternative way.
Using event binding and call the following function that proceeds to activate the router.
You need to inject first the Router class like this.

e.g (Working)

```js
//custom.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
      selector: 'app-custom',
      templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./custom.component.scss'],})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {}

  changeRoute(pageName){
    this.router.navigate([pageName]);
  }

}
```

In html:

```html
 <!-- custom.html --> 
<ion-item (click)="changeRoute(menu.title)" lines="none" *ngFor="let menu of pageTitle"> <ion-icon [name]="menu.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon> <ion-label>{{menu1.title | titlecase}}</ion-label> </ion-item>
```